# JPA/Hibernate switch schema programmatically

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, jpa

I'm working at the moment on a new project which has following requirement:

Several database schemas are holding the same tables with identical structure (in short: one entity for multiple schemas).

Is it possible to switch between those schemas by code? Want I want to achieve is:

User selects schema B and updates some entities in this. After this he does a insert in schema A and so on. I know that I could do this by basic JDBC by providing the schema to the statements but if I can avoid that I would do so.

Maybe some other java ORM can do this? I'm only familiar with JPA / Hibernate.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use separate `SessionFactory`s or `EntityManagerFactory`s, one for each schema.
Since you said that the user **selects** schema A or B, you can use something like this:

```
public enum Schema {
    A, B
}

public EntityDaoImpl {

    // Create and populate the map at DAO creation time (Spring etc.).
    private Map<Schema, SessionFactory> sessionFactoryBySchema = ...; 

    private Session getSession(Schema schema) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = sessionFactoryBySchema.get(schema);
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); // ... or whatever
    }

    public void saveEntity(Schema schema, Entity entity) {
        getSession(schema).save(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution should not need any further configuration when it's running. Sorry didn't mentioned that in my question

Comment: What are you referring to by further configuration?

Comment: Other schemas with this kind of entites could be imported to the database at any time. I need something which works dynamically. Obtaining the corresponding schemas by meta data and accessing them

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Hibernate without adding some SessionFactorys since Hibernate needs the schema at configuration time (SessionFactory creation to be exact). If new schemas will be created while the application is running, you could "lazily" obtain the SessionFactory needed for the selected schema - if it doesn't yet exist, you will create it programatically - new Configuration().buildSessionFactory() and add it to a map similar to the one I posted in the answer.

Comment: Are there likely to be classloader issues in this kind of scenario?  I'm wondering if Hibernate is going to create classes of the same exact name for each schema, and maybe get them befuddled.

Comment: I don't think so, I am not aware of Hibernate "enriching" the classes or something like that.

Comment: I accept this question here because it is the only clean solution for this scenario. I solved my problem by using pure JDBC empowered with springs JDBC template.